# Want to return all months data in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having below table

```
Month_Id Count
1        2
2        1
6        2
10       3
```

how can i get below output

```
Month_Id Count
1         2
2         1
3         0
4         0
5         0
6         0
7         0
8         0
9         0
10        0
11        0
12        0
```

Comment: You can do it with a calendar table, if you google for it you'll get many examples.

Comment: Month's 6 and 10 do not show the correct results, btw.

Comment: left join table to `generate_series(1,12)`

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
WITH months AS (select generate_series(1,12) as m) 
SELECT months.m, mytable.mycount
  FROM months, mytable
 WHERE months.m = mytable.id;
```